# Is it possible to access event listeners from component in Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom component in Vue.js(2) as:

```
Vue.component("modal-panel", {
    props: {
        id: {
            required: true
        },
        title: {} ,
        size: {
            validator: function(value) {
                return !value || value=="lg" || value=="sm";
            }
        }, 
        confirmLabel: {
            "default": "Yes",
        }, 
        closeLabel: {
            "default": "No"
        },
        confirm: {
            type: Function
        }
    },
    //...
    template: `
        //...
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary confirm" data-dismiss="modal" v-on:click="$emit('confirm')" v-if="confirm">{{confirmLabel}}</button>
        //...
    `
}
```

And this is the code using component

```
<modal-panel title="New User" id="userModal" @confirm="doSomething">...</modal-panel>
```

As seen from the component code, confirm has been inserted into the props and on the button code in the template there is a conditional rendering according to whether confirm listener attached or not. However, button is not rendered. I checked component dom and properties, but there is not such an info.

Is it possible to make conditional rendering according to whether a specific listener attached to component in vue.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Vue 2.4, Vue components have a `$listeners` property.

> Contains parent-scope v-on event listeners (without .native
> modifiers).

This is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners). You can determine whether or not the parent is listening to a particular event by examining the `$listeners` property.

---

**Original Answer**

It's not generally good practice for a component to reach out of itself to determine things.

I would recommend instead that you have a `confirm` callback property. You can pass a function in as a property. Then you can decide to show/hide the button on whether you received the callback or not.

```
Vue.component("modal",{
  props:["confirm"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Modal</h1>
      <button v-if="confirm" @click="confirm">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  `
})
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WjxBbO).

**Edit**

You *can* determine if there is a handler defined on a component for a given event, but it requires examining an internal Vue property, and you should only use this at your own risk.

```
Vue.component("modal",{
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Modal</h1>
      <button v-if="hasConfirmHandler" @click="$emit('confirm')">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  `,
  computed:{
    hasConfirmHandler(){
      return !!this._events["confirm"]
    }
  }
})
```

The `_events` property of the component will contain the handler, if a handler is defined from the parent.

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WjGZYz).

Comment: Thanks Bert. Yes that is an option, I was just curious about whether the other method is possible. As I understand, it is not.

Comment: @yavuzkavus Technically, it's possible but you have to examine the internal API of Vue. In the component, the `_events` property will list the event handlers that are on the component. You could inspect to see if there is a handler for `confirm`.

Comment: @yavuzkavus I added an example to that effect, but I would recommend the callback approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your function with `v-bind` or `:` instead of just passing it as a string. So use `:confirm` syntax:

```html
<modal-panel title="New User" id="userModal" :confirm="doSomething"></modal-panel>
```

Then in component template simply use `v-on:click="confirm()"`:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary confirm" data-dismiss="modal" 
  v-on:click="confirm()" 
  v-if="confirm">
  {{confirmLabel}}
</button>
```

Comment: He's not passing `confirm` in the question, he has an event listener using the `@handler` syntax.